# ls -l output different in 2 server

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have recently ssh to 2 servers , what bother me is that the output of ls -l
are quite different :

Server1 :

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 informix informix  276 Oct 13 16:45 aaa
drwxrwxr-x. 2 informix informix   51 Oct 13 14:51 esqlc
drwxrwxr-x. 2 informix informix  101 Oct 13 08:58 libevent
-rw-rw-r--. 1 informix informix 3107 Oct 12 16:37 mpmc.hpp
```

Server2:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 informix informix  1964 2015-09-21 09:45:24.000000000 +0800 addrinfo.h
-rw-rw-r--. 1 informix informix  9126 2015-09-21 09:45:26.000000000 +0800 config.h
drwxrwxr-x. 2 informix informix  4096 2015-10-15 16:34:28.301211516 +0800 libevent/
-rw-rw-r--. 1 informix informix  2258 2015-10-15 16:10:12.741742196 +0800 client.cpp
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 informix informix 13518 2015-10-15 16:34:28.334211656 +0800 client.exe*
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 informix informix   100 2015-10-15 16:33:48.706031980 +0800 compile.sh*
```

What bashrc parameter should I change so that I will have output of "ls -l"
like server1 , not like server2  ?

Edit :

Why ls -l output of server2  has "*" in client.exe and compile.sh  ?

Comment: **ls** has nothing to do with Bash or its settings (`bashrc`). Also it's not recommended to parse the output of **ls**.

Comment: ls by default uses the locale time settings for time.Bottom of this page provides more info https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/649727-how-to-change-the-linux-date-and-time-simple-commands

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Actually it does as it uses the time settings from bash(provided the shell is bash) and OP may want to change them to keep the format the same.

Comment: Try `unalias ls` or `\ls -l` to get same results.

Comment: @Cyrus , after I type \ls -l , the output is exactly like server1 , thanks

Comment: Informix (= Windows Services For Unix) isn't Linux, and IIRC prefers BSD shells. Is this actually on a Linux server, and is this actually Bash?

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９, I meant in the sense that the two of them aren't strongly coupled; an opposite example would be GNOME settings affecting the behavior of GNOME programs. The `TIME_STYLE` environment variable mentioned in that article can be set in multiple ways, `bashrc` is only one of them.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu you said it has **Nothing** to do with bashrc, but as values set in bashrc can affect it, I would argue that it does.

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９, yes, perhaps my choice of words was unfortunate. Though using a similar reasoning, even a [rootkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit#User_mode) could affect **ls**, but I don't think that's the thing most users have in mind.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu It isn't typical though that a rootkit would be used to edit the time format , yet it is much more normal for people to change the format of the things in the bashrc. In the same vein though, i wouldn't have claimed it had nothing to do with rootkits.

Answer (score 3):

The difference in the above two outputs is the format of the time.

1. locale format
2. full ISO format

You can specify a time-style option as shown below

```
ls -l --time-style="full-iso"
ls -l --time-style="locale"
```

The locale option depends on your locale (language & regional settings) which you can set in your `bashrc`. You can read more about [formatting file timestamps](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Formatting-file-timestamps.html) in the manual for GNU coreutils which include **ls**.

Comment: Just note that the locale format could be long ISO though, or pretty much anything.